# Slow item filtering in PivotTable (.ManualUpdate = True NOT WORKING)

Tags: vba, filtering, pivot-table

I try to filter my PivotTable with VBA. Disable "Calculation, Events, Screen and PivotTable.ManualUpdarte = True" did not help. I use VISIBLE property of certain item. Does anybody know how to do this job FASTER?

Please find attached example, there is a sub "SLOWcode":
https://docs.google.com/file/d/1GjUpkC8-u2s5dOequEp9jp7HSaLvVP_1/edit?usp=docslist_api&filetype=msexcel

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a pretty extensive article on filtering Pivots on external ranges quickly at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

You'll find extensive code as well as a thorough discussions there. The takeaway point of that article is that it takes longer to *set* the `.visible` status than to *read* it. So you should first check the `.Visible` property of each item, and then only change it if you have to.  The efficient tweak I do to the kind of approach you're taking in your code is as follows:

- Add all Search terms to a dictionary (or collection, if you prefer)
- Try to add each PivotItem to that same dictionary.
- If that last step caused an error, you know that this PivotItem is
  in your list of search terms. In this case, you can check what the
  current visible status is of the PivotItem. If it’s NOT visible,
  make it visible. If it IS visible,  do nothing
- If this didn’t cause an error, you know that this PivotItem IS
  NOT in your list of filter terms. In this case, you again check what
  the current visible status is of the PivotItem. If it’s visible,
  hide it. If it’s already hidden, do nothing

This approach is quite efficient in that it only changes the .visible status of the PivotItem if it has to. Which is good, because as per the article I linked to, this is the bottleneck. And the general approach of using a Dictionary (or collection) is very efficient, compared to other ways I’ve seen on line that use say applicaiton.match to check the PivotItem against a variant array or (far worse) against the original FilterTerms range in the worksheet.

Later in that acticle, I show how you can radically speed things up further if you hide all but one PivotItem programatically using a Slicer-connected copy of the Pivot with the field of interest in the temp into a Page field with .EnableMultiplePageItems set to False. This forces the original PivotField to have the same filter setting – just one item visible. Meaning you don't have to set .`Visible = false` on other Slicer Items you want to hide.

Comment: Great!!! Slicer does that trick how to select just on item with VBA. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick of selecting only one item in Pivot table with VBA:

```
             ActiveSheet.PivotTables(destTable).PivotFields(mainText).ClearAllFilters
                ActiveSheet.PivotTables(destTable).ManualUpdate = True

                varFirstItemVisible = mynames(0) ' e.g.: first searched item

                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(helpTable).PivotFields(mainText)
                    .Orientation = xlPageField
                    .ClearAllFilters
                    .EnableMultiplePageItems = False
                    .CurrentPage = varFirstItemVisible
                End With


                Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(helpTable), ActiveSheet.PivotTables(helpTable).PivotFields(mainText))
                sc.PivotTables.AddPivotTable ActiveSheet.PivotTables(destTable)
                sc.PivotTables.RemovePivotTable ActiveSheet.PivotTables(destTable)
```

Then just loop through your wished items and make them visible ;D